Please help understanding the equation for player $i$ 's payoff to mixed strategy profile $\sigma$
In the beginning chapter of the book Game Theory by Fudenberg a game is shown as an example (https://i.sstatic.net/uzJlf.png) and a function is suggested to calculate the payoff. Player $i$'s payoff to profile $\sigma$ is given by
$$
\sum_{s\in S}\left(\Pi^I_{j=1}\sigma_j(s_j)\right)u_i(s)
$$
What keeps bugging me is that I think, strictly speaking, $s$ should not have the subscript $j$ so that
$$
\sum_{s\in S}\left(\Pi^I_{j=1}\sigma_j(s)\right)u_i(s)
$$
If you could point out and correct where I'm getting confused, it would be really appreciated.

My gues is that (1) is more restrictive than (2). In (1) $s$ is a vector of length $I$ but $\sigma_j$ only depends on $s_j$ the $j$'th entry of $s$. In (2) $\sigma_j$ could depend on all entries of $s=(s_1,...,s_I)$.  But I have not read the book so I'm only basing this on the question. And of course this does not answer whether such a restriction is valid or not in the given context.

The interpretation of $\sigma_j(s_j)$ is that it's the probability with which player $j$ uses his pure strategy $s_j$. In your image example, that would be the probability of the row player choosing a particular row or the column player choosing a particular column. Given that each player decides independently, the product $\Pi_{j=1}^I\sigma_j(s_j)$ represents the joint probability that outcome $s$ occurs when each player $j$ uses mixed strategy $\sigma_j$.
In contrast, $\sigma_j(s)$ would signify the probability that player $j$ assigns to the pure strategy profile $s$. In other words, $\sigma_j(s)$ is the probability of a particular cell in the matrix game. But $j$ cannot "choose" a particular outcome of the game, as the players are assumed to be non-cooperative in this context. It also doesn't make sense to multiply the probability that each player assigns to an outcome $s$, i.e. $\Pi_{j=1}^I\sigma_j(s)$.
In the textbook, the last paragraph page 5 has a detailed example of how the payoff function is applied to the game in Figure 1.1. That could help with understanding.
